# Prove that $\left(\frac2p\right) = 1$ if $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$ and $\left(\frac2p\right) = -1$ if $p \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$ using ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and let $\alpha = [X] \in R=\mathbb F_p[X]/\langle X^4+1\rangle$, and $y = \alpha +  \alpha^{-1}$

I've proven:

1) $\alpha$ is a primitive eight root of unity in $R$.

2) $y^2 = 2$ and $y^p = \alpha^p + \alpha^{-p}$.

$\alpha^{-p} = {(\alpha^{-1})}^{p}$ right ?

3) $y^p = y$ if $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$ and $y^p = -y$ if $p\equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$.

However I need help proving that $\left(\frac2p\right) = 1$ if $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$ and $\left(\frac2p\right) = -1$ if $p \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$. This should be accomplished using what I've already proven according to the text.

Please dont forget comment on my "$\alpha^{-p} = {(\alpha^{-1})}^{p}$ right ?".

Thanks.

Comment: I'd let $\pi(X)$ be a prime factor of $X^4+1$ and consider the ring $R=F_p[X]/\langle\pi(X)\rangle$, since this is a field, letting you do some simplifications.

Comment: $R$ is indeed a field. Let $F$ be a field and $f \in F[X]$ an irreducible polynomial. Then $R=F[X]/\langle f \rangle$ is a field.

Comment: No, $R$ is not necessarily a field. $X^4+1$ is not necessarily an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Ohh, guess you are right. But I really would like my answer to be based on 1,2,3.
However since the problem assume $\alpha^{-1}$ exists doesn't that imply we are working in a field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, right, $\alpha^{-p} = \left(\alpha^{-1}\right)^p$.

Regarding the Legendre symbol, note that

$$y^p = \left(y^2\right)^{(p-1)/2}\cdot y = 2^{(p-1)/2}\cdot y = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\cdot y.$$

Comment: why $$2^{(p-1)/2}\cdot y = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\cdot y.$$ ? and could you tell me how we can assume $\alpha^{-1}$ exists, since we don't know if $R$ is a field. Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: Is it because $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) \equiv 2^{(p-1)/2} (\mod p)$$ ?

Comment: First $\alpha^{-1}$. The polynomial factored out is $X^4+1$, which means $\alpha^4 = -1$, and hence $\alpha^8 = 1$, so $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha^7$. Second, the Legendre symbol, yes, precisely, because $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv \left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \pmod{p}$.

Comment: I know  $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)  \equiv 2^{(p-1)/2}$$ but this just means that $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = 2^{(p-1)/2} + pk$. But then $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) \cdot y = (2^{(p-1)/2} + pk) \cdot y = 2^{(p-1)/2} \cdot y$$ why ?

Comment: @user111854 We're working over $\mathbb{F}_p$, so all integers, like $2^{(p-1)/2}$ or $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$ are reduced modulo $p$/represent their residue class modulo $p$. In $\mathbb{F}_p$, we have the equality, $a^{(p-1)/2} = \left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$, not only the congruence.

Comment: No we are working over $R=\mathbb F_p[X]/\langle X^4+1\rangle$ ?

Comment: $[2^{(p-1)/2}+pk] = [2^{(p-1)/2}] + [pk] = [2^{(p-1)/2}]$ if and only if $pk \in \langle X^4 +1 \rangle$ which is true ?

Comment: Which is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra. In the case $2^{(p-1)/2}$ resp. $\left(\frac2p\right)$, the prime ring $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $R$ is not left.

Comment: not left ?

So we have $(\frac 2 p) \cdot y = y$. In the case of this ring and the result $(\frac 2 p) = 1 + pk$ we have $[(\frac 2 p)] = [1 + pk] = [1] + [0] = [1]$. However this result is only valid for $R$ right ? We used the $\mathbb F_p$, so this doesn't prove the result $(\frac 2 p) = 1$ if $p \equiv 1,7 \mod 8$ for a general ring ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. On the one hand, we have $y^p=c_p\cdot y$, where $c_p=\pm1$, depending on the remainder of $p$ modulo $8$. On the other hand, since $y^2=2$ in $R$, we have $y^p=y^{p-1}\cdot y=2^{(p-1)/2}\cdot y$. So we have $c_p=2^{(p-1)/2}$ in $R$. But both, $c_p$ and $2^{(p-1)/2}$ belong to the prime ring $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $R$, so we have $c_p=2^{(p-1)/2}$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. And that means in $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $c_p\equiv2^{(p-1)/2}\pmod{p}$. And in $\mathbb{Z}$, we also have $\left(\frac2p\right)\equiv2^{(p-1)/2}\pmod{p}$. So $c_p\equiv\left(\frac2p\right)\pmod{p}$. But ...

Comment: $c_p$ as well as $\left(\frac2p\right)$ are either $1$ or $-1$, so we have not only congruence, but equality, $$\left(\frac2p\right) = c_p = \begin{cases} \,1 &, p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}\\ -1 &, p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod{8}.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks man, you are very good at this. Have you solved tons of these problems ?

Comment: Let me put it thus: forty years ago I had considerably less experience.

Comment: But to conclude $c_p = 2^{(p-1)/2}$ in $R$ we only know $2^{(p-1)/2} \cdot y = c_p \cdot y$ which implies $(2^{(p-1)/2} + c_p) \cdot y = 0$ but to conclude $2^{(p-1)/2} = c_p$ we need to know  that $R$ is a domain, but we don't know this ? We don't know if $R$ is a field, since we don't know if $X^4 + 1$ is irreducible.

Comment: But $s = c_p + 2^{(p-1)/2} \in \mathbb{F}_p$, and all elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ are either $0$ or invertible. So $s\cdot y = 0 \Rightarrow (s = 0 \lor y = 0)$. We know $y \neq 0$, since $y^2 = 2 \neq 0$ (or we could see that $y = \alpha + \alpha^{-1} = \alpha + \alpha^7 = \alpha + \alpha^3\cdot \alpha^4 = \alpha - \alpha^3$), so we can conclude $s = 0$.

Comment: How do you show $\mathbb F_p$ is a subring of $R$ ? Through isomorphism or directly ?

Comment: Isomorphism. $\mathbb{F}_p \hookrightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[X] \to \mathbb{F}_p[X]/\langle X^4+1\rangle$. Since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field, the ring homomorphism is injective.

Comment: Thanks so much @Daniel Fischer.
I see that the unique ring homomorphism is injective on its image, and since the size of $\mathbb F_p$  is equal to the size of the image (subring: size much divide $p^4$), it is a isomorphism and $[1] \in \mathbb F_p \rightarrow [1] \in R$ implies that $[k] \in \mathbb F_p \rightarrow [k] \in R$ for any $k \in \mathbb Z$ - Please confirm if I'm right, since it has been quite a journey for me to realize this.
My only questions remaining is: $s \cdot y = 0$ - we have $s \in \mathbb F_p$ through isomorphism and we know $s$ is either zero or invertible ...

Comment: However does $y \in \mathbb F_p$ ? If yes, why? If not then our isomorphism doesn't provide any information on why $s \cdot y$ cannot be zero, since invertibility (not a zero-divisor) of $s$ only counts when it being multiplied by an element from $\mathbb F_p$ through isomorphism ? Also I know char $R = p$, where $|R| =p^4$. So $[p] = [0] \in R$ which implies $p \in \langle X^4 + 1 \rangle$. However how can $p$ be some multiple of $X^4 +1$ ?

Comment: The "for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$" depends on interpretation. We have $[k+p] = [k]$ in both $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $R$, so we get only $p$ distinct $[k]$ overall, the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ has kernel $p\cdot\mathbb{Z}$. $y$ does not lie in the image of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in $R$, let us call that image $P$ to distinguish, but since $P$ is a subring of $R$, if $t \in P$ is invertible in $P$, it is also invertible in $R$. Since $P$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$, every nonzero element of $P$ is invertible (both, in $P$ and $R$). Note $p = 0$ (or $[p] = [0]$, so $[p] = [0]\cdot(X^4+1)$.

Comment: Thanks, for any $k \in \mathbb Z$ I mean that $[k] \in \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$ correspond to $[k] \in R$ where $[k]$ in both cases is equal to $[k \mod p]$ ? Or if $k = pn + m$ then in both cases (rings) $[k] = [pn + m] = [m]$. $[p] = [0] \Rightarrow p - 0 = p \in \langle X^4 + 1 \rangle$. I dont understand your argument $[p] = [0] \cdot [X^4 + 1]$ ? We know $X^4 + 1 \in \langle X^4 + 1 \rangle$ so $[X^4 + 1] = [0]$ and still $p -X^4-1 \in \langle X^4 + 1 \rangle$ for this to be true. I see now that $-X^4 + (p-1) = (p-1)(X^4 + 1)$

Comment: Yes to the first. Regarding the second, we're factoring out the ideal $\langle X^4+1\rangle$ from $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. That ideal contains $0$, since $0 = 0\cdot(X^4+1)$. But $0 = p$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, so $p = p\cdot(X^4+1) = 0\cdot (X^4+1) \in \langle X^4+1\rangle$.